# Is it possible to have a "key combination" to decide where to log in, windows or ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, dual-boot

I have dualbooted ubuntu onto my windows system, and every time I restart, it takes me to a screen where I select what I want to boot into, whether that be **windows boot loader (windows)** or ubuntu.

Then I select and press enter and it goes on from there.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if so, I want a way to **define a key combination** that I can press on start up, such as maybe **Ctrl + W**. When the computer is starting and I press **Ctrl + W**, then it automatically boots into windows without asking me. Similarly I want one like **Ctrl + U** for ubuntu, so it skips that entire screen and just goes directory to ubuntu.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you use native UEFI boot or BIOS/MBR? If mbr, do you use grub2?